# mySQL Sum Production_Needed Group BY Part_ID

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

Want to generate a result of Open orders where Production is needed.  At issue is each part may have more than one open order.  With the GROUP BY my code gives me only one order but does give me the total Production_Needed (which is also a negative in value for orders with enough inventory).

Does my SUM(...) as Production_Needed need to be in the WHERE ?
Thanks,

```
SELECT part.part_ID AS Part_Part_ID, 
   part.Inventory, part.part_number, 
   ord.part_id AS Order_Part_ID, 
   ord.order_type, ord.quantity_ordered, ord.quantity_shipped, 
   SUM(ord.quantity_ordered - ord.quantity_shipped - part.Inventory) AS Production_Needed 
FROM production_orders ord 
JOIN production_part part ON ord.part_ID = part.part_ID 
WHERE ord.is_Active = True AND ord.order_type = 0
GROUP BY Order_Part_ID 
ORDER BY part.part_number ASC
```

Data Production_Part part

| Part_ID | Part_Inventory | Part_Number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12500 | 97-528 |
| 2 | 0 | FC2569 |
| 3 | 1000 | 39367 |

Data Production_Orders Ord

| Order_Part_ID | Order_Type | Quantity_Ordered | Quantity_Shipped |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 8000 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1000 | 500 |
| 2 | 0 | 1000 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | 10 | 0 |

Desired Result - Only Parts that need production

| Part_ID | Quantity_Ordered | Quantity_Shipped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1000 | 500 |
| 2 | 1000 | 0 |

Comment: Please edit your question with some example data (source and result of your query)

Comment: Logically I think you want to do your aggregation of order quantities BEFORE you do the subtraction from inventory.  Here's why... say you have 3 orders for Item A of 10x0, 20x0, 30x10 and you have 5 in stock. This means in total you have 60 ordered and 10 are shipped.  if you do it the way you outlined your results would be (10-0-5)+(20-0-5)+(30-10-5)  Note how it subtracts the 5 from inventory from EVERY order.  you only want that to happen once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested: need a sampled data set and structure for testing:

This creates an inline view and totals the inventory order amounts then stubtracts it from the inventory to determine if there is a production needed to fulfil open orders.  I'd have to use some additional analytical functions if we needed to do this on an order by order basis however; or join these results back into the orders...

--Show parts which lack inventory to fullfill outstanding open orders.

```
SELECT 
    P.Part_ID as Part_Part_ID
  , P.Inventory
  , P.Part_Number
  , O.Part_ID as Order_Part_ID
  , UnDel_Units-coalesce(P.Inventory,0) as Production_Needed  --use coalesce incase no part record exists for some reason.
FROM Production_Part P
RIGHT JOIN (    --use right join just incase part record doesn't exist for some reason
  SELECT part_ID, SUM(quantity_ordered-quantity_shipped) as UnDel_Units
  FROM PRODUCTION_ORDERS
  WHERE IS_ACTIVE=TRUE
    and ORDER_TYPE=0
  GROUP BY PART_ID) O  --derived table "O" for orders showing sum ottal by part of units undelivered
 on O.Part_ID=P.Part_ID
WHERE UnDel_Units > coalesce(P.Inventory,0)
--  If inventory is > undelivered units for the part, ignore as additional production isn't needed
```

Comment: "if we needed to do this on an order by order basis however; or join these results back into the orders..."  How would would this be accomplished on an Order by Order basis?  I am attempting to get all Parts that need production and also list the respective orders